# How to ensure that Android automatically runs my Sync Adapter?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to understand how to use a sync adapter. I have gone through the official android tutorial and while I now have a basic working example I'm still unclear regarding some of its features. In particular I'm unsure about the following statements made on the tutorial's intro page:

> [The sync adapter] allows you to automate data transfer based on a variety of criteria, including data changes, elapsed time, or time of day. In addition, ***the system adds transfers that are unable to run to a queue, and runs them when possible.***

What does the system consider a failed transfer here? Would a failed request to my server count? And if that was the case how would I let the system know that my update failed?

> The system only runs your data transfer when the device has network connectivity.

I assume this means that my sync adapter will not be called if there is no network. But if that is the case then when will it be called?

> Your data transfer is also scheduled in conjunction with data transfers from other apps.

Does this happen automatically or are there any settings I need to change to let the system know I want this to happen? And how would I test that this takes place?

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set automatic synchronization using following code

```
    Account newAccount = new Account(ACCOUNT,ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    mResolver = getContentResolver();
    // Turn on automatic syncing for the default account and authority
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, AUTHORITY, true);
```

But you need to add this permission in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
```

I add periodic sync for particular seconds ,

Third parameter indicate no of seconds for periodic synchronization

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(newAccount, AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY, 90);
```

**Official document** - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addPeriodicSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long%29